# Making box in the middle of the world by exact percentage from the overall space

Tags: netlogo

I want to make box in the middle of the Netlogo world

I managed to make a box but in the corner of my space the location of the origin is corner and the max pxcor = 9 and the maxpycor = 9

The code for 25%

```
  to setup-area-25%
  ask patches with [pxcor >= 5 and pycor >= 5] [ set pcolor blue ]   
  end
```

and the other code for 50 %

```
   to setup-area-50%
  ask patches with [pxcor >= -5 and pycor >= 5] [ set pcolor blue ]
  end
```

I want to make blue area represent 25 and 50 % of the world but in the middle of the world I tried to use in radius but it did not give me a right area.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty way that won't necessarily give you the *exact* percentage that your looking for, but could be good enough, depending on what you are trying to do:

```
to make-box [ pct box-color ]
  let side round sqrt (count patches * (pct / 100))
  let x min-pxcor + ceiling ((world-width  - side) / 2)
  let y min-pycor + ceiling ((world-height - side) / 2)
  ask patches with [
    pxcor >= x and pxcor < x + side and
    pycor >= y and pycor < y + side
  ] [
    set pcolor box-color
  ]
end
```

Calling `make-box 25 red` should give you a red square that is about 25% of the overall area, calling `make-box 50 blue` should give a blue square that is about 50%, etc.

The code uses the square root of the desired box area as the side of the box to draw. Not all numbers are perfect squares, however, and this is why you don't always get the exact percentage that you are looking for. You could try to look for the closest factor pair instead, but in some cases, they're just not very square. For example, 50% of the default NetLogo world size is 544.5 patches. If we round this up, we get 545 patches: not a perfect square. The closest factor pair that will give you exactly 545 is 109 * 5, which is probably not what you want.

**Edit:**

Here is a version that uses the closest factor pair, thereby always giving an area equal to the desired percentage of the world (rounded to an integer number of patches, but that can't be avoided). Just be warned that the box may end up being much more rectangular than square; so much that it very well may wrap around the world. You'll have to vary world-size or requested percentage if you want to avoid that.

```
to make-box [ pct box-color ]
  let n round (count patches * (pct / 100))
  let h height (floor sqrt n) n
  let w (n / h)
  let x min-pxcor + ceiling ((world-width  - w) / 2)
  let y min-pycor + ceiling ((world-height - h) / 2)
  ask patches with [
    pxcor >= x and pxcor < x + w and
    pycor >= y and pycor < y + h
  ] [
    set pcolor box-color
  ]
end

to-report height [ h n ]
  report ifelse-value (n mod h = 0) [ h ] [ height (h - 1) n ]
end
```

The algorithm for finding the closest factor pair loosely follows [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16267018/487946).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but I really need perfect percentages and in the middle because i also need 75 but by this rule it will not calcualted as 75, thank you again

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, I am not expert in math but when I tried to choose 75 % it give me also 50 % and also it gave me Oblong shape not square in the middle, The idea is to have square by different percentage as control strategy and surrounded by the rest of the space  so the four edges needed to be surrounded by uncontrol area ( square in the middle), I am really sorry for my bad English. thank you again very much

Comment: This is what I tried to explain: If you use the first version of the code, your box will be square, but the percentage may not be exact. If you use the second version, the percentage will be exact (unless the rectangle wraps around) but your box may not be square. You can't have it both ways. My advice would be: use the first version, so that you are guaranteed a square box but make your world big enough that the percentage is close enough to what you want.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, I understand you now,   but can I ask you if I tried to make the world 100 patch can I color the 25 or 50 or 75 patch surrounding the centre of the world?

Comment: 100 patches would be very small. The default NetLogo world is 33*33, and thus 1089 patches. If you want your world to be exactly 1000 patches big, then it won't be square. And the boxes in the middle would not be squares either because neither 250, 500 or 750 have integer square roots. Maybe it's possible to find a world size where 25%, 50% and 75% will all be squares. I don't know.