# How to reshape vector into sqare matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a vector of certain size and I want to reshape it into a square matrix. Here is an example: Let's say the vector is of size 784. Then I would create a matrix of size 28x28. In Matlab I would do it with the following command:

```
reshape(x,28,28)
```

Of course it can be possible that it is not possible to have an exact square matrix. In this case the matrix should as squarish as possible.

How can I do this calculation? That means how can I calculate the values `a` and `b` in `reshape(x,a,b)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with `a` equal to the square root of `numel(x)` rounded down. If that number doesn't divide `numel(x)`, subtract `1` and try again. That way you end with `a` equal to the closest integer to `sqrt(x)` (from below) that divides `numel(x)`. `b` would then be `numel(x)/a`, but you can simply use `[]` as the third argument to `reshape`:

```
a = floor(sqrt(numel(x)));
while mod(x,a)
    a = a-1;
end
result = reshape(x,a,[]);
```

Example:

```
x = 1:20;
```

gives

```
result =
     1     5     9    13    17
     2     6    10    14    18
     3     7    11    15    19
     4     8    12    16    20
```

Comment: Thank you. But what is n in your example?

Comment: @machinery Sorry. It should be `a`.  Corrected now

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

```
x = rand(1, 784);
divisors = find(rem(numel(x), 1:numel(x)) == 0);
[~, idx] = min(abs(divisors - sqrt(numel(x))));
x = reshape(x, divisors(idx), numel(x) / divisors(idx));
```

Let me explain:

Suppose you have a vector named `x`:

```
x = rand(1, 784);
```

First, you find the divisors of the size of `x`:

```
divisors = find(rem(numel(x), 1:numel(x)) == 0);
```

Then, you proceed to choose the divisor which is closest to the square root of `x`'s size:

```
[~, idx] = min(abs(divisors - sqrt(numel(x))));
```

Finally, you reshape `x` using that divisor (and the corresponding multiple):

```
x = reshape(x, divisors(idx), numel(x) / divisors(idx));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a simple problem to find closest factors of an integer. You need to use the MATLAB answers to the question [Input an integer, find the two closest integers which, when multiplied, equal the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266931/input-an-integer-find-the-two-closest-integers-which-when-multiplied-equal-th). From that question if you use the answer that provides the function `findIntegerFactorsCloseToSquarRoot`, you can use the following code to reshape.

```
[a, b] =  findIntegerFactorsCloseToSquarRoot(numel(x));
reshape(x, a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first check whether the number is prime or not by `isprime(784)`.

Then you can use `prime_factors = factor(784)` to get the integer factorization of the number. (Depending on the MATLAB version you may use `ifactor(784)`)

The rest needs just a little more work on `prime_factors`.